# How to style marks in rc-slider library?

Tags: reactjs, npm, slider, rc-slider

I am working on my react-js app and suddenly facing some issue related to word wrap in rc-slider npm [https://www.npmjs.com/package/rc-slider] . anyone know about how to style marks in rc slider. if yes,  please help me to style my slider like this ... up and down markers [image]`your text`

```
<Slider dots min={0} marks={marks} step={null} defaultValue={0} >
```

I try every thing from my side....

Answer (score 0):

```
.rc-slider-mark-text:nth-of-type(even) {
  color: red !important;
  transform: translate(-50%, -33px) !important;
}
```

:nth-of-type(even) /* same, represents every even elements that has the same expanded element name */

try this solution

[for reference](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-paa9nb?file=index.css)